# Combine SQL UPDATE STATEMENTS

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am trying to combine these five update statements. I'm sure this is simple but I am new to SQL and can't figure the logic out.

```
$usqlM1 = "UPDATE tblmaincircles SET mcName= '".$_POST['mcNameM1']."' WHERE mcID='M1';"
$usqlM2 = "UPDATE tblmaincircles SET mcName= '".$_POST['mcNameM2']."' WHERE mcID='M2';";
$usqlM3 = "UPDATE tblmaincircles SET mcName= '".$_POST['mcNameM3']."' WHERE mcID='M3';";
$usqlM4 = "UPDATE tblmaincircles SET mcName= '".$_POST['mcNameM4']."' WHERE mcID='M4';";
$usqlM5 = "UPDATE tblmaincircles SET mcName= '".$_POST['mcNameM5']."' WHERE mcID='M5';";
```

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `CASE` statement can do this.  You can add a where clause so the system doesn't have to evaluate each record and improve performance if MCID is indexed.

```
UPDATE tblmaincircle set mcname = case when mcid = 'M1' then 'McNameM1'
                                       when mcid = 'M2' then 'McNameM2'
                                       when mcid = 'M3' then 'McNameM3'
                                       when mcid = 'M4' then 'McNameM4'
                                       when mcid = 'M5' then 'McNameM5' end
where mcid in ('M1','M2','M3','M4','M5');
```

Comment: @Craig Howell: in this case you can't use prepared statements but you should sanitize the post variables to avoid sql injection.

Comment: @WilliamBurnham do you have any good links to sanitize post variables. I have heard about this and want to be mindful of it in future development.

Comment: @Craig Howell: if you look directly in the php manual you can find information about sanitizing variables and sql injection: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php, http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php.